# What is the point of minimizing the square difference between a prediction and expected value, versus taking the absolute value of each sum?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Machine Learning course for example, we are computing the cost function, J(Theta_1)

I have an hypothesis function h-theta(x^i) that I want to be as close as possible to the real world recorded value h^i.

To record the error that I wish to minimize (such is the context in the Coursera Machine Learning course), I sum together every pair (x^i - y^i) which is plainly-spoken SumOfAll(predicted - recordedInThePast)
and then square it.

Is the only reason they do this is to get a positive result for each? In that case why not use absolute value instead of squaring them?

[image]

but suppose instead of squaring the differences in the cost function, you use absolute value instead:

[image]

It's just going to produce a cost function with a different curve.
So the question remains, why square the difference?

Comment: Try reading [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your post more readable.

Comment: I recall a professor explaining this to me in 2010. Wish I could remember what he said! (But there is a satisfactory answer, that much I remember)

Comment: @AndrewChin Thank you.. Thats going to take a little time but I'll get it done asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mean Absolute Error is a valid metric.

However Mean Squared Error and Root Mean Squared Error has analogues to Euclidean distance, which allows statisticians to lift the body of architecture from Euclidean geometry that has been well studied since 0.

The absolute value function is not a smooth function (i.e. it has a kink in it) and that means that it doesn't play well with some of the tools of calculus.  This makes squared errors easier to work with.

The squared error "punishes" large deviations more harshly, and overlooks small errors.  This is generally considered to be a good thing.